# How to find the screen-size-in-points of a Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: screen, screen-resolution, samsung-galaxy-s7

Does anyone know, or know how to determine, the dimensions of the Samsung Galaxy S7 screen in points?

The reason I ask is because I'm trying to test the responsiveness of a website on the Samsung Galaxy S7, by using Chrome's built-in responsiveness checker.  It has preset settings to test different devices, but the Samsung Galaxy S7 is not one of them.  The tool *does* allow me to enter a custom screen dimension (see attached image).  Unfortunately I can't figure out what dimensions to enter for the Samsung Galaxy S7--it's not asking for the resolution and it's not asking for the physical dimensions in inches/centimeters. The displayed dimensions for each device seem to correlate to the device's dimensions in points, (see [this page](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) for my rationale).  I may be misinterpreting something though.
[image]

Comment: Galaxy S7: 5.1-inch diagonal, 2560x1440 (QHD) panel, LCD density at 640 (default) or 560 (condensed). What other info are you looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more research, I found my answer:  360 x 640, which are the same dimensions as the Galaxy S6, which are the same dimensions as the few preceding Galaxy S models.

But I still don't know what these dimensions are called.  I found three different websites, each giving them a different term:

- [design.google.com](https://design.google.com/devices/):  "width x height in dp"
- mydevice.io/devices:  "CSS width and CSS height"
- viewportsizes.com:  "viewport size"

Answer (score 2):

The metric 360 x 640 is in dp (device-independent pixels) and it is the dimension of the viewport at a 1x base size. This is not the same as the resolution, or physical pixel size. This is because the S7 has an XXXHDPI density factor of 4x, which means every graphic must be scaled x4 when exporting assets for this device. The resolution in actual pixels is 1440 × 2560, but one pixel on this device = 4px on a MDPI (medium-density) device, such as the Samsung Galaxy Ace (which has a viewport size of 360 x 640 dp AND a resolution of 360 x 640px).

See Google Material.io -- it lists the device metrics for many Android devices.